# Manage SharePoint Search thesaurus

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

I need a tool to manage the SharePoint Search Thesaurus. I am aware of the `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication` command and the corresponding .txt file for deploying the thesaurus, but I need a tool that content creators can use.

Does anyone know of such a thing?

Comment: Check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cliffgreen/2010/07/15/manage-and-generate-the-sharepoint-thesaurus-files-with-a-sharepoint-list-part-2-of-2/

Comment: What version of SharePoint? The thesaurus files format changed in 2013. You can just use notepad.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott SP2013 (I'm on the same team)

Comment: Great, so the solution would be even easier for you in 2013. You just need a CSV file and regular upload. You could just create a folder watcher that looks for an updated file and then import it into SharePoint.